# What is the best ASCII char to separate a string?

Tags: python, c++, c, string, unicode

I work on a system on which customer can send me unicode string encoded as utf-8. at some point, I pack/serialize (C++) whose data using a kind of comma separated list like:

```
fieldName:value,other fieldname:value, etc....
```

that string is goind out of a process andif catched by a python script to extract a dictionnary:

```
 {"fieldName":"value", etc..... }
```

To extract that I use a simple regex `re.compile(ur"(.*?):(.*?)(?:,|$)", re.UNICODE)`.
But I know that users can use `,` and `:` in the string they send so I'm search for the best ASCII code I could use at C++ level to replace the comma I use for now ?

Is `\xF8` (248) a good choice, if it must be something user cannot enter with a keyboard !
Any help & advice would be welcome.

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)

Comment: `Ø` (0xf8) is not a good choice, it's easy to enter at least on some scandinavian keyboards.

Comment: There is no "best" choice, as any such choice depends on the data being encoded.

Comment: Do you know the input is valid UTF-8? After you've checked that, you can use bytes which are invalid in UTF-8. 0xF8 is such a byte. @JoachimIsaksson: The Unicode code point 0xF8 is encoded as 0xc3 0xb8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use JSON instead of an in-house format.

Rationale:

1. It looks like JSON anyway already
2. no issues with delimiter characters. It always goes wrong sooner or later, see for example `$IFS`-hell on unix/posix systems.
3. easily human-readable, in contrast to using special characters that are probably not displayed correctly and can't be entered easily by a human (mainly for debugging purposes)
4. negligible overhead (if any)
5. No hassle parsing and generating JSON in about every language in existence.
6. JSON libraries exist for C/C++ in many variations and with many licenses, so it's not an issue even for proprietary software to include one of these.

Comment: Thanks for that advice I finally added a bit of complexity in my c++ code to pass my map of string into a json writer and I used the python json parser, and now all the strange unit test I have a green! So thks

Answer (score 13):

I'd use one of the [ASCII field separator control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators); these have the advantage that they have a standardized meaning:

```
^\  28  1C  FS  ␜   File Separator
^]  29  1D  GS  ␝   Group separator 
^^  30  1E  RS  ␞   Record Separator    
^_  31  1F  US  ␟   Unit separator
```

> Can be used as delimiters to mark fields of data structures. If used for hierarchical levels, US is the lowest level (dividing plain-text data items), while RS, GS, and FS are of increasing level to divide groups made up of items of the level beneath it.

Or use a real format like JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

\x0D or \x0A is a simple choice, if you don't have multiline input strings and these can be displayed easily. Or tab (\x09) if user cannot enter it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best—I don't know if there is
a "best"—but I've seen '`|`' used a lot for this.

If it doesn't have to be visible, or be entered from a keyboard,
there are a number of control characters which can do the trick:
ASCII alone defines four: FS, GS, RS and US (for field
separator, group separator, record separator and unit
separator), codes 0x1C-0x1F; these would be naturals.

The most universal solution, of course, would to use quoted
strings, with escape characters.  This is more difficult both to
parse and to generate, however.